# Why does gcc throw an implicit-fallthrough warning?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Given the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

enum one {
    A, B
};

enum two {
    AA
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    enum one one = atoi(argv[1]);
    enum two two = atoi(argv[2]);
    
    if ((one != A && one != B) || two != AA)
        return 1;
    
    switch (one) {
    case A:
        switch (two) {
        case AA:
            return 2;
        }
    case B:
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it using using `gcc -Wimplicit-fallthrough test_fallthrough.c` I get the following warning

```
test_fallthrough.c: In function 'main':
test_fallthrough.c:21:3: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
   21 |   switch (two) {
      |   ^~~~~~
test_fallthrough.c:25:2: note: here
   25 |  case B:
      |  ^~~~
```

What is it trying to warn against and what can I do so that it does not warn (I would prefer to avoid adding comments such as `/* Falls through. */`)

Comment: `I would prefer to avoid adding comments such as /* Falls through. */` `what can I do so that it does not warn` ? Use that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `break` in the first switch statement, it may fallthrough to the sencond case, it can execute `case A` and afterwards `Case B`, hence the warning.

```
//...
switch (one)
{
case A:
    switch (two)
    {
    case AA:
        return 2;
    }
    break; //breaking case A removes the warning.
case B:
    return 3;
}
//...
```

Side note:

- Using `argc` to check if `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are present is always a good idea.

Comment: It looks like clang is able to determine that the inner switch will never allow the flow to continue so it doesn't warn, however gcc was not able to notice that so a break is required for it to know

Comment: @finks, from my experience clang is usually "smarter" than gcc.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does gcc throw an implicit-fallthrough warning?

Well, because it may fallthrough.

> What is it trying to warn against

A fallthrough from `case A` into `case B` when `two != AA`.

> what can I do so that it does not warn

On gcc lower then 7 use a comment, ie. [one of the markers that disable the warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wimplicit-fallthrough):

```
/* falls through */
```

On gcc above 7 you could [use a attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Attributes.html):

```
__attribute__((__fallthrough__));
```

On gcc above 10 you could use [the attribute from C2x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2052.pdf):

```
[[fallthrough]];
```

--

Note that `if (one != A || one != B || two != AA)` is not really checking anything, as `one != A || one != B` will always be true. I guess you meant to do like `if ((one != A && one != B) || two != AA)`. Still the `-Wimplicit-falthrough=` warning is not taking that `if` into account anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, compiler checks for a `break` statement after every `case` body, so that it can ensure the program flow (fallthrough) is not a mistake.

In your case, `case A` body does not have a `break`, letting the execution to continue for `case B` also, when the `switch` statement matches that of `case A`.

```
switch (one) {
    case A:
        switch (two) {
        case AA:
            return 2;
        }
         // <------ no break here, flow will continue, or fall-through to next case body
    case B:
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```